# Is there a more elegant, extensible way of adding multiple conditions to a JQuery validation custom method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've put together a few custom methods in the past for the JQuery validation plugin, but this is the first where I've wanted to check against multiple conditions.

Its a simple scenario, where I am trying to detect the presence of html in a field. I don't need an extensive Regex, I just want to tell the user that html is allowed in a client side fashion. I am of course blocking the server side submission if there is html in the field value, but I want a nice user experience.

There must be a simpler way of looking for a few key elements, could do it with looping through an Array?

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.validator.addMethod("findhtml", function(value, element) {

var commentclean = new Boolean();

if (element.value.indexOf("<") != -1) 
{
    commentclean= false;
    //alert('found <');
 }
else if
(element.value.indexOf("http") != -1){
    commentclean= false;
    //alert('found http');
}
else
{
    commentclean= true;
    //alert('nothing found')
}

return this.optional(element) || ( commentclean );

}, "* match the string");

});
</script>
```

Comment: you should use regex for finding html markup. For example string `0 < 1` doesn't contain html. Using regex in clien side NOT so expensive as you guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.validator.addMethod("findhtml", function(value, element) {

        var commentclean = true,
            disallowed = ['<', 'http'];

        for (var i=0, len = disallowed.length; i<len; i++) {
            if (element.value.indexOf(disallowed[i]) != -1) {
                commentclean = false;
                break;
            }        
        }

        return this.optional(element) || ( commentclean );

    }, "* match the string");

});
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks very much, a short, extensible way of adding a few more conditions to the client side check.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var el=$('<div>').html(value);
commentclean = (   el.html() == el.text()
                && el.text().indexOf('http') == -1
);
```